# strange behaviour of VB.net exe - vs2005

Tags: vb.net

Ran ProcMon and then ran my vb.net exe.

Saw steps that I am not calling explictly

an example from the PML file is

```
Thread : 4248
class  : File System
Operation : CreateFile
Result: SUCCESS
Path  : C:\Documents and Settings\Admin

Desired Access: Read Data/List Directory, Synchronize
Disposition:    Open
Options:    Directory, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Open For Backup
Attributes: n/a
ShareMode:  Read, Write, Delete
AllocationSize: n/a
OpenResult: Opened
```

and this is followed by

```
Thread : 4248
    class  : File System
    Operation : QueryDirectory
    Result: SUCCESS
    Path  : C:\Documents and Settings\Admin

0:  .
1:  ..
2:  .ezlm20jk
3:  Application Data
4:  Cookies
5:  Desktop
6:  Favorites
7:  Local Settings
8:  My Documents
9:  NetHood
10: NTUSER.DAT
11: ntuser.dat.LOG
12: ntuser.ini
13: PrintHood
14: Recent
15: SendTo
16: Start Menu
17: Templates
```

and see such logs for entire drive...

This seems to slow the launch the application...

Answer (score 0):

Try checking that you have correctly set up a filter in ProcMon pointing to your executable, otherwise ProcMon will collect all system events.

Comment: I just checked. The 'processname' column in my entire log points to my application.exe

Comment: from my app?? if yes - then which part would you recommend that i post?

Comment: Yeah from the app, do you have it long? Maybe try running performance proffiler on the application to see what takes that time? [ANTS Performance Profiler] (http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/). Otherwise try checking for loops and file operations.

Comment: i had procmon open with it set to only capture any traffic for my application and that is what i posted. Is there a way to set proc mon against my source code? my source code is 9050 lines, so would be hard to post without breaking NDA

Comment: I hope it's not all in one file? :) I would recommend using a profiler, it will highlight you which line in particular takes CPU time. ProcMon may not be that useful for understanding general problems.

Comment: yea its all one nice file. old dev guy liked things in one file..:) which profiler do you recommend?

Comment: It's likely then there is a problem with design and refactoring is needed. It seems like SOLID principle are violated and there are more bugs to discover. I would start with debugger and profiler http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/

Comment: You can see other profilers discussed in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers

Comment: how would i trace what exactly is placing those logs in proc mon??

Comment: in profiler you can see which operations take more time, you can nail it down to methods and loops. Try also searching any System.IO calls in the file itself